# Andengine sprite touch event on layers

Tags: android, andengine

I am developing a game using **AndEngine** in which on the game screen i have **2 layers - backlayer** and **frontlayer**. On the **backlayer** i have attached **1 player** sprite and several **baddies** sprite. On the **frontlayer** i have attached a **tree** sprite. Now what i want is that the **baddies** move around the screen in a zig-zag way throughout the game and when the user **touches** the **baddie**, they will be **popped(disappear/detached)** but when they go **behind** the **tree** they should not be **popped** when the user **touches** the **tree** on the area where **baddie** is but **not visible**.
  I have transparent background for the image of tree and since there are several region in the tree where there are no leaves so that area is also transparent and the baddies are visible in that region and also they can be **popped** in that region.

I am done with all the stuffs, only the problem I face is **baddies are popped even when they are behind the tree and not visible to the user**.

Kindly please help me...

Answer (score 0):

If you know when they are back in the tree, then disable the touch area for that sprite or do nothing when touched if they are back.

Comment: how to determine if they are back in the tree since image of tree is having several area which is transparent and in that area baddie is visible to the user..

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of PixelPerfectSprite where it will return true only if you are touching the tree, and will return false if you are touching in between leaves (i.e in transparent region)

After this if your fingure is colliding with tree as well as your character then don't pop up else if it collides only character then pop up